# ServiceStack - Instance per http request - (Console application) - (Ninject)

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm having a problems configuring instance per http request in service stack. I am running a console app and trying to use Ninject as my container.

I would like an instance to last for 1 full request. I would like to know how I can configure this.

I would like an example showing how I could start the lifetime of the dependency when the request starts and how to dispose that same instance when the request ends.

Could anyone give me an example of how to do this in autofac and ninject.

```
public class OutboundHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase 
{
    public OutboundHost() : base("StarterTemplate HttpListener", typeof(SmsService).Assembly) { }

    protected override void ProcessRequest(System.Net.HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Processing request");

        base.ProcessRequest(context);
    }

    public override void Start(string urlBase)
    {

        base.Start(urlBase);
    }

    public override void OnEndRequest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("End processing request");

        base.OnEndRequest();
    }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container) {


        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        RegisterEntityFrameworkNinject(kernel);
        RegisterDependenciesNinject(kernel);

        LogManager.LogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory();
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Container");
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        container.RegisterValidators(typeof(SendSmsValidator).Assembly);
        Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
        Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

        Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature() { RequiredRoles = new string[] { } });


        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(), }));

        SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
        {
            CustomHttpHandlers = {
                { System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new RazorHandler("/notfound") }
            }
        });

        InitializeLookupTables(kernel);
        container.Adapter = new NinjectIocAdapter(kernel);
    }

    private void RegisterDependenciesNinject(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(c => LogManager.LogFactory.GetLogger(typeof (ConsoleLogger))).InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<ISendSmsIntenda>().To<SendSmsIntenda>();
    }

    private void RegisterEntityFrameworkNinject(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IEntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>().To<EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>();
        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>();
        kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();
        kernel.Bind<ILookupTableFactory>().To<EntityFrameworkLookupTableFactory>();

        kernel.Bind<IDataQuery>().To<DatabaseQuery>();

        kernel.Bind<IContextFactory>().To<DefaultContextFactory<OutboundContext>>().InSingletonScope()
              .WithConstructorArgument("connectionStringName", GetConnectionString());
    }

    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Outbound"].ConnectionString;
    }

    private void InitializeLookupTables(IKernel kernel)
    {
        using (var kernelContext = kernel.BeginBlock())
        {
            var contextFactory = kernelContext.Get<IContextFactory>();
            var frameworkContext = kernelContext.Get<IContextFactory>().GetContext() as IFrameworkContext;
            var unitOfWork = kernelContext.Get<IUnitOfWork>();


            contextFactory.GetContext().RegisterLookupTable<SmsStatusType, SmsStatusEnum>();
            frameworkContext.SaveLookupTableChanges();

            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }
    }
}


public class NinjectIocAdapter : IContainerAdapter
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;
    private readonly Container container;

    public NinjectIocAdapter(IKernel kernel, Funq.Container container)
    {

        this.kernel = kernel;
        this.container = container;
    }

    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return this.kernel.Get<T>();
    }

    public T TryResolve<T>()
    {
        return this.kernel.TryGet<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Autofac and NInject? Presumably you just mean NInject?

Comment: Ninject example. But i'm also looking for an example using autofac.